# ServerConfig is unsupported by arquillian

Tags: maven, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

Using arquillian for unittest and integration test of EJB in Wilfly 8 application server. Arquillian fails to recognize the property "serverConfig" to choose the server start up configuration and its missing in supported property names, so its always starting with configuration of "standalone.xml" but am in need to run with "standalone-full.xml", below is warning capture while start the test and supplied pom.xml and arquillian.xml, is there any dependency missing to overcome this?

```
WARNING [org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.MapObject] Configuration contain properties not supported by the backing object org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.embedded.EmbeddedContainerConfiguration
Unused property entries: {serverConfig=standalone-full.xml}
Supported property names: [managementAddress, modulePath, password, bundlePath, managementPort, jbossHome, managementProtocol, cleanServerBaseDir, username]
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">D:/wildfly-8.1.0.Final</property>
        <property name="modulePath">D:/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules</property>
        <property name="serverConfig">standalone-full.xml</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>EJBTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>EJBTest</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
    <arquillian-version>1.1.4.Final</arquillian-version>
    <arquillian-wildfly-version>8.1.0.CR2</arquillian-wildfly-version>
    <arquillian-transaction-version>1.0.1.Final</arquillian-transaction-version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -JUNIT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- rquillian itself-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${arquillian-version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- this is in an extention to arquillian it is optional-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${arquillian-transaction-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- this is container adapter for wildfly-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${arquillian-wildfly-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this is the wildfly emb.container - BUT eventually it is not a fully blown emb.container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>                
            <version>${arquillian-wildfly-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Fork every test because it will launch a separate AS instance -->
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <!--
                    <jboss.home>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final</jboss.home>
                    <module.path>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules</module.path>
                    -->
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Solution**

Replaced dependency artifact id

```
<artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
```

with

```
<artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
```

Comment: Looks like you only have one server config there. If you only have one, you don't need to add the qualifier for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closer examination, you're using the embedded wildfly:

```
       <!-- this is container adapter for wildfly-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>${arquillian-wildfly-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- this is the wildfly emb.container - BUT eventually it is not a fully blown emb.container-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>                
        <version>${arquillian-wildfly-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

You should be using either managed or remote if you want to use the full profile.

Comment: can't get you clear am very new to this so technical what change is exactly required, pls clarify

Comment: The artifactid will need to change to the container type you plan on using.

Comment: ya it working after replacing the `<artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>` with `<artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>`